# Is there anything known about this transcendental equation?

Tags: transcendental-equations

I came across the following problem:
solve

$(a^2+s^2)\sinh s + 2 b s = 2 s \cosh s$

for $s$, with $a$ and $b$ real parameters.

Is there anything known about the solution(s) of this problem?

Comment: If $s$ is a solution then $-s$ is also a solution, so by symmetry you can already say that $0$ is a solution. The problem then reduces to finding a positive solution

Comment: Setting directly $s=0$ indeed shows that it is a solution. However there are cases where other solutions exists (I know this by numerical experimentation).

Comment: I didn't say that other solutions do not exist, I just gave one root, we should investigate further to see wether there exists another one.

Comment: This equation looks interesting. I am afraid that only numerical methods could be used. Are they particular ranges for $a,b$ ?

Comment: In my problem I would take $|b|\leq 1$ but nothing else.